# Access FormControl inside custom Angular Component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I'm creating a custom angular component which shows an error tooltip when my FormControl (Reactive Forms) is invalid.
But I don't know how I can access the FormControl inside my custom component to check whether or not it is marked as valid.

**What I want to accomplish**

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
     <input formControlName="name" type="text" />
     <custom-validation-message formControlName="name">My special error message!</custom-validation-message>
  </div>
```

**Already encountered stuff**

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'surveyType'

Fixed this by implementing ControlValueAccessor with NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR even though I don't want to alter the value. I also added an injector to access the NgControl.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-validation-message',
    templateUrl: './validation-message.component.html',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, useExisting: ValidationMessageComponent
    }]
})
export class ValidationMessageComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    public formControl: any;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        super();
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        const model = this.injector.get(NgControl);
        this.formControl = model.control;
    }

    public writeValue(obj: any): void {
    }
    public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    }
    public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    }
    public setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    }
}
```

**Current Problem**
The model.control is undefined. After inspecting the model I found out that the model is as good as empty only the _parent is a full representation of my form. The model._parent.controls does contain all the controls of my form. But still I don't know the current control.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

as I get you point you just want to make a componnet for display form control validation message the other answer explane why ControlValueAccessor is not the case here ,you just want to pass a control form reference to the component then check the validation state , Thomas Schneiter answer is a correct why but I face the case and it 's hard to keep get refrance by get method and sometime we are in sub group and form array so I idea is to just pass the name of the form control as string then get the control reference.

*CustomValidationMessageComponent*

```js
@Component({
  selector: "custom-validation-message",
  templateUrl: "./custom-validation-message.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./custom-validation-message.component.css"]
})
export class CustomValidationMessageComponent {
  @Input()
  public controlName: string;

  constructor(@Optional() private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {} 

  get form(): FormGroup {
    return this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
  }

  get control(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get(this.controlName) as FormControl;
  }
}
```

*template*

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="control && control?.invalid && control?.touched">
  <ul>
    <li *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">
      this is required field
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="control.hasError('pattern')">
      pattern is invalid 
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="control.hasError('maxlength')">
      the length is over the max limit
    </li>
     <!-- <li *ngFor="let err of control.errors | keyvalue">
       {{err.key}}
     </li> -->
  </ul>

</ng-container>
```

and you can use it like this

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <label>
   First Name <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
   <div>
       <custom-validation-message controlName="firstName"></custom-validation-message>
   </div>
 </label>

 ...
  
</form>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-message)

> you can check this angular library [ngx-valdemort](https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com/#/) created by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) where it solve this problem perfectly.

Comment: I've just tried out your approach and it works great.
I am updating my own framework and ngx-valdemort gave me another idea.
Having one container with all the possible errors inside is way better than having to duplicate the custom-validation-message for each possible error.

Comment: How is that `@Optional() private controlContainer: ControlContainer` injected? Is that automatically happening inside of the formGroup?

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter the ControlContainer inject by angular and give us access to the formGroup instance from the parent check this and include a talk by Kara Ericksons https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/nested-forms-in-angular/

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correctly, the `<custom-validation-message>` should just display validation errors of a reactive forms input.

A ControlValueAccessor is used to create a custom input. What you want to do is to create a simple component with an Abstract control as input. The component could look like this:

ts:

```
@Input() public control: AbstractControl;
...
```

With this, you can access the formControls properties like `invalid`, `touched` and `errors` inside of the custom component.
html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="control?.invalid && control?.touched">
  <ul>
    <li class="validation-message" *ngFor="let error of control.errors">
      {{error}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

then add the control that should display errors as an input

```
<custom-validation-message [control]="form.get('name')"></custom-validation-message>
```

Comment: hi , `control.errors` is an object of key value not any array so this case you will get an error like this `NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` you can fix this problem like this `<li *ngFor="let err of control.errors | keyvalue">
       {{err.key}}
     </li> ` 

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can access the `FormControl` of a custom `FormControl` component (`ControlValueAccessor`). Tested with Angular 8.

```html
<my-text-input formControlName="name"></my-text-input>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-text-input',
  template: '<input
    type="text"
    [value]="value"
  />'
})
export class TextInputComponent implements AfterContentInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input('value') value = '';

  // There are things missing here to correctly implement ControlValueAccessor, 
  // but it's all standard.

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (ngControl != null) {
      ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }


  // It's important which lifecycle hook you try to access it.
  // I recommend AfterContentInit, control is already available and you can still
  // change things on template without getting 'change after checked' errors.
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    if (this.ngControl && this.ngControl.control) {
      // this.ngControl.control is component FormControl
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This causes `Error: Circular dep for TextInputComponent`

Comment: I don't see how this causes circular dep. It is likely to be something in your imports.

Comment: I notice that you didn't provide NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR `providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: MyCustomComponent, multi: true }],` is it the same as what you do in the Constructor and check if it's null ?

Comment: Yes, it is explained here https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#ngcontrol

Comment: That might be the reason why @GennadiyLitvinyuk had circular dep, that he was providing NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR and shouldn't in this case.

Comment: @RuiMarques, @huantao you are right, i have had `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` in my component

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check your approach. A `CustomControlValueAccessor` should only be used for real form controls. It's a creative approach, it may works somehow, but I wouldn't go for it.

There are other ways than injection to access the `FormControl` inside your validation component:

1) Define the `FormGroup` without the `FormBuilder` so that you'll have access to the form controls directly:

```js
  firstName: new FormControl('');
  lastName: new FormControl('');

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName,
    lastName
  });
```

Then in your html you can pass the form control to the custom-validation-message:

```html
<custom-validation-message [control]="firstName">My special error message!</custom-validation-message>
```

2) Use the `FormBuilder` nevertheless, but with a getter function:

```js
// component

get firstName() {
    return this.profileForm.get('firstName') as FormControl;
}
```

```html
<custom-validation-message [control]="firstName">My special error message!</custom-validation-message>
```

3) or as Thomas Schneiter wrote: access the control in the template with:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input formControlName="name" type="text" />
   <custom-validation-message [control]="form.get('firstName)">My special error message!</custom-validation-message>
</form>
```

Comment: This was my original aprouch.
I wanted to change to get rid of the "complexity" (form.get(...)).
Thats why I wanted something that looked similar to how you bind input controls.